# Bitwise Operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'm new here but had some questions about my Computing 2 HW.

Given the main function:

```
void set_flag(int* flag_holder, int flag_position);
int check_flag(int flag_holder, int flag_position);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int flag_holder = 0;
    int i;
    set_flag(&flag_holder, 3);
    set_flag(&flag_holder, 16);
    set_flag(&flag_holder, 31);
    for(i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", check_flag(flag_holder, i));
        if(i % 4 == 0)
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

We're supposed to complete `set_flag`, and `check_flag`, and its supposed to display:

`1000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 1000`

Now I'm really struggling to understand this. is `flag_holder` supposed to equal 0 the whole time? My professor said to use bitwise and no multiplication. But it looks like I could just implement an array of 32 '0's and set the 3rd, 16th, and 31st elements as 0s? I apologize in advance for the messy set up, and thanks to any who actually read this and help!

Comment: "I apologize in advance for the messy set up" - do you really write all your code on one line? Either way, i've fixed it for you so that people can actually help you.

Comment: Also, how is anyone supposed to know what your problem is when you don't show us all of your code? If you're implementing `set_flag` and `check_flag`, do you know if those work or not? Please fix this.

Comment: "But it looks like I could just implement an array of 32 '0's". You could but that's not the point of the exercise. You are meant to manipulate the bits in the `int` variable. So it's not clear what help you want from us.

Comment: is `int flag_holder` supposed to equal 0 the whole time? No.  `set_flag(&flag_holder, 3);` certainly changes the value of `flag_holder`.

Comment: The idea for `set_flag` is something like: `*flag_holder = *flag_holder | (1 << flag_position)`

Comment: Note that setting bit 31 (numbered from 0..31) of a signed quantity is likely to lead to 'undefined behaviour'.  That's a bit tricky — and if the `main()` program was given to you, not something you can fix.  Just be aware that bit manipulation of signed values involving the most significant bit is tricky.  It is far better to use unsigned integer types; then the behaviour is defined.

Comment: To complete this task, you need to understand bitwise logical operators AND, OR and NOT, as well as shift left.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the similarity between multiplication and bitwise

left shift & right shift are used to set flags mostly

```
2 = 0010
```

when you left shit 2 by 1, all the bits are shifted to left and with zero appended.

```
0010 << 1 
0100
```

and the result will be

```
0100 = 4
```

and further left shifting make `0100` to `1000 = 8`

left shifting is similar to multiply by 2
and right shifting is similar to divide by 2

**Setting flags**

```
set_flag(&flag_holder, 3);
```

the function will more or less be like this

```
void set_flag( int *flag_holder, int shifter) {
*flag_holder = *flag_holder | 1 << shifter;
}
```

what this will do is that 3rd bit is set without affecting any other bits